# Are sphinxsearch.com and sphinx-doc.org related?

Tags: sphinx, python-sphinx

In python, there's a tool called sphinx (sphinx-doc.org) to generate documentation. An example output is the one generated by paramiko (ssh library):

http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/1.16/

It includes a tiny but pretty convenient search engine.

On google, if you try "sphinx advanced search options" or that kind of stuff, you stumble upon sphinxsearch.com, which is apparently a c++ search engine.

I think both projects are fully unrelated, but I'm not 100% sure. Just like to confirm.

thanks

Comment: Only related in that they happen to have a similar name.

Comment: Thank you @mzjin, you can close if you want. I just thought it could help other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two projects are completely unrelated.

I find that for Google searches, adding the word "python" will usually restrict my results to those involving the documentation tool.